# Filtering JSON by key value using pipes

Tags: json, typescript, angular, pipes-filters

I have an array of objects in the following format:

```
{
            img: './app/images/codeeval.png',
            name: 'codeEval',
            repo: 'https://github.com/Shooshte/CodeEval',
            description: 'CodeEval challenges solutions written in javascript and posted to gitHub.',
            github: true,
            demo: false,
            finished: true
        }
```

Now what I am trying to do is to write a custom pipe, that takes a string, and then checks if the object has this string set as true. So let's say I pass in `'demo'`, it would return all the objects that have `demo: true`.

my html:

```
<div *ngFor="#p of pages | pagesFilter: 'demo'" class="portfolioPageContainer">
    <img [attr.src]="p.img" class="portfolioThumbnail">
    <h2>{{ p.name }}</h2>
    <a [attr.href]="p.repo">
        <div>
            <p>{{ p.description }}</p>
        </div>
        <p class="portfolioRepoLink">See the Code!</p>
    </a>
</div>
```

my component:

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';
import {ViewEncapsulation} from 'angular2/core';
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'portfolio',
    templateUrl: '/app/views/portfolio.html',
    styleUrls: ['../app/styles/PortfolioMobile.css', '../app/styles/PortfolioOther.css'],
    pipes: [pagesFilter],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})

export class PortfolioComponent {
    pages = [{
        img: './app/images/placeholder.png',
        name: 'veryNiceWords',
        repo: 'https://github.com/Shooshte/veryNiceWords',
        description: 'A hobby app, made to enable posting, rating and sharing quotes over social networks. Work in progress.',
        github: true,
        demo: false,
        finished: false
    },
        {
            img: './app/images/placeholder.png',
            name: 'ZIC IJS',
            repo: 'https://github.com/Shooshte/ZIC',
            description: 'Refurbishing of on old library webpage with AngularJS.',
            github: true,
            demo: false,
            finished: false
        },
        {
            img: './app/images/weather.png',
            name: 'Show the Local weather',
            repo: 'http://codepen.io/shooshte/pen/NxOwOX',
            description: 'A freeCodeCamp exercise, designed to show the local weather.',
            github: false,
            demo: true,
            finished: true
        },
        {
            img: './app/images/calculator.png',
            name: 'Calculator',
            repo: 'http://codepen.io/shooshte/pen/qbjJdy',
            description: 'A freeCodeCamp exercise, which requires you to build a javascript calculator.',
            github: false,
            demo: true,
            finished: true
        },
        {
            img: './app/images/github.png',
            name: 'MTGO Draft Replayer',
            repo: 'https://github.com/Shooshte/MTGO-Draft-Replayer',
            description: 'A simple web app that opens a MTGO draft log file, and re-creates the draft from it.',
            github: true,
            demo: false,
            finished: false
        },
        {
            img: './app/images/codeeval.png',
            name: 'codeEval',
            repo: 'https://github.com/Shooshte/CodeEval',
            description: 'CodeEval challenges solutions written in javascript and posted to gitHub.',
            github: true,
            demo: false,
            finished: true
        }];
}

@Pipe({ name: 'pagesFilter' })
class pagesFilter implements PipeTransform {
    transform(pages: Array, [key]): string {
        return pages.hasOwnProperty(key);
    }
}
```

I get the following error in the console:

> angular2.dev.js:23730 EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise):
>   Unexpected piped value 'undefined' on the View of component
>   'PortfolioComponent'

Can somebody please point out what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hoisting isn't supported for classes. You need to define your pipe before your class:

```
@Pipe({ name: 'pagesFilter' })
class pagesFilter implements PipeTransform {
  transform(pages: Array, [key]): string {
    return pages.hasOwnProperty(key);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'portfolio',
  templateUrl: '/app/views/portfolio.html',
  styleUrls: ['../app/styles/PortfolioMobile.css', '../app/styles/PortfolioOther.css'],
  pipes: [pagesFilter],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class PortfolioComponent {
  (...)
}
```

**Update**

Your pipe should return an array not a boolean:

```
@Pipe({ name: 'pagesFilter' })
class pagesFilter implements PipeTransform {
  transform(pages: Array, [key]): string {
    return pages.filter(page => {
      return page.hasOwnProperty(key);
    });

  }
}
```

Comment: This solved the initial issue, but now I am getting: angular2.dev.js:23730 EXCEPTION: Cannot find a differ supporting object 'false' in [pages | pagesFilter: 'demo' in PortfolioComponent@0:5]